# How to add metadata details and description in Opencart?

Tags: opencart

Can anyone help me in adding meta data details to manufactures in `opencart`? I am looking for adding meta data keyword, description and manufacturer description similar to products or categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your opencart database and add the following extra field to `oc_manufacturer` table

```
ALTER TABLE oc_manufacturer ADD COLUMN `description` text NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE oc_manufacturer ADD COLUMN `meta_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE oc_manufacturer ADD COLUMN `meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE oc_manufacturer ADD COLUMN `meta_keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL;
```

**Edit manufacturer controller file and below code**

**Edit file:** catalog/controller/product/manufacturer.php

Find code:

```
$this->document->setTitle($manufacturer_info['name']);
```

Replace below code with that:

```
$this->document->setTitle($manufacturer_info['meta_title']);
$this->document->setDescription($manufacturer_info['meta_description']);
$this->document->setKeywords($manufacturer_info['meta_keyword']);
$data['description'] = $manufacturer_info['description'];
```

**Now edit view file of manufacturer products**

**Edit file:** catalog/view/theme/[ACTIVE THEME]/template/product/manufacturer_info.twig

And add description variable where you want to place the manufacturer description

```
{{ description }}
```

**Note:** Refresh modification by click on the refresh button in **Extension -> modification** page in admin panel

Now add your description and metadata into `oc_manufacturer` table